# Update a couple of values in nested array MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

I would like to update a couple of elements in they match given values:
Example : I have a collection with this structure:

```
 {
 "_id" : ObjectId("52936a0270c68c04063f0300"),
  "channel" : "1",
  "content" : "145548",
  "keywordsValues" : [
                        [ObjectId("52816d3370c68c2c1c4b0500"), ObjectId("52816d3370c68c2c1c9f0500")],
                        [ObjectId("52816d3370c68c2c1c510500"), ObjectId("52816d3370c68c2c1c890500")],
                        [ObjectId("52816d3370c68c2c1c550500"), ObjectId("52816d3370c68c2c1c850500")],
                        [ObjectId("52816d3370c68c2c1c6b0500"), ObjectId("52816d3370c68c2c1c990500")]
                    ]
}
```

And I need to update "keywordsValues" field (just one of the couple in the array [])

Something for example update the 2nd element in keywordsValues:
**If we found [firstId,secondId] in keywordsValues field then update the second secondId**

```
$database->Measurements->update(
array('keywordsValues'=>
array(new MongoId(52816d3370c68c2c1c4b0500),new MongoId(52816d3370c68c2c1c9f0500)',$atomic'=>'true')),
array('$set'=>array('keywordsValue.$'=>new MongoId($idNewValue))));
```

But this doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

try


    `array('$set'=>array('keywordsValue'=>new MongoId($idNewValue))));`

instead of

```
array('$set'=>array('keywordsValue.$'=>new MongoId($idNewValue))));
```

i hope it help to you!